# Defining this objects is making another undefined?

Tags: javascript, debugging, object, node.js

I have this code:

```
sys.puts(JSON.stringify(data[0].name));

var userData = {
    name: data[0].name,
    screenname: data[0].screen_name,
    id: data[0].id,
    url: data[0].url,
    description: data[0].description
 }
```

When I comment out the creation of the userData object everything works fine, meaning it writes that value to the console correctly. When I put it back in I get this error:

```
sys.puts(JSON.stringify(data[0].name));
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Any ideas why this would be happening?  This is all within the same function.

Comment: Might be an obvious question, but are you certain this code is only being executed once? In my case, I had two simultaneous callbacks executing the same code, one with `data[0]` populated, one without; so it looked like the value was magically disappearing, but it was in fact the second call which had no data.

Comment: This looks like a job for a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/). The code as-is isn't complete, so the problem isn't reproducable.

Comment: Thanks guys, I don't quite understand what was going on yet but it is definitely a callback issue. I was calling the same function for different things and passing in a different callback, or so I thought. Debugging I separated it into two functions and made the callbacks static and it fixed the problem, now I just need to figure out what I was doing it wrong. Anyways, thanks for pushing me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [guard operator](http://seanmonstar.com/post/707078771/guard-and-default-operators) to validate the object before accessing its properties:

```
JSON.stringify(!!window["data"] && data.hasOwnProperty("length") && data[0].hasOwnProperty("name") && data[0].name)
```

As an alternative use a try/catch block:

```
try
  {
  JSON.stringify(data[0].name)
  }
catch(e)
  {
  throw("Error")
  }
```

**References**

- [Guard and Default Operators of JavaScript](http://seanmonstar.com/post/707078771/guard-and-default-operators)